# How to compare two values?

Tags: php, mysql

From my code I am able to enter a value for first time (when database is empty), second time it is not working even for the different users with a different plant name. If user 1 enters a plant name like Apple for first time it is saved, but not any following times.
Is this a correct way of writing MySQL code, when I want to compare two values?

```
$plant = $_SESSION['plant'];
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$q = mysqli_query($con, "select plantname='$plant' from tree where
user = '$user'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) {
  Header('Location: home.php');
  exit;
} else {
  $query = "insert into tree(plantname,user)
  values('$plant', '$user')";
  $q = mysqli_query($con, $query)or die("Could Not Perform the Query");
  Header('Location: home.php');
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify `second time it is not working`? Do you get an error? Replace `"Could Not Perform the Query"` with http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php. Also this is open to SQL injections. You should parameterize the query.

Comment: As already alleviated too, but worth double mentioning, use parameterised queries! Your query is open to SQL injections and not once do you check if any of these values exist.

Comment: Thanks for reply guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Mistaken to your `query` you have to pass your query condition after selecting your table `from`

```
$plant=$_SESSION['plant'];
$user=$_SESSION['user'];

$q = mysqli_query($con,"select * from tree where user='$user' AND plantname='$plant'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($q)>0){
    Header( 'Location: home.php' );
    exit;
}else{
    $query="insert into tree(plantname,user) values ('$plant','$user')";
    $q=mysqli_query($con,$query)or die("Could Not Perform the Query");
    Header( 'Location: home.php' );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Beware of sql injection, that code is very unsecure